# SQLCipher: Use of unresolved identifier 'sqlite3_key'

Tags: ios, swift, sqlcipher

App is coding with Swift, SQLCipher installed and had tried to compile the app without using database, it worked well, but when I tried to use sqlite3_key, it gives an error:  Use of unresolved identifier 'sqlite3_key'.

I have defined -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC in CFLAGS and added #import  in bridgeHeader.h

Can anyone help to solve this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your bridging header you need to add this before importing sqlite3.h:

```
#define SQLITE_HAS_CODEC 1
```

Source: https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/use-of-unresolved-identifier-sqlite3-key/1305/10

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added in Build settings objective-C Bridging Header with name  "YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h"

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a quite old question, there are still someone will encounter the same issue. 
The problem is with the SQLCipher document,

> In the bridging header add `#import <sqlite3.h>`.

This is wrong statement actually, you should add `#import "sqlite3.h"` instead. Because XCode also come with a sqlite3 module by default, if you import it with diamond bracket, it will use the default one from XCode. The default one does not have ciphering feature, that's why you cannot use sqlite3_key() and related functions.